# Keyboard/language bug (in R)

Tags: r, keyboard

I've had a reoccurring issue with R on several different computers, and I know someone else who has also had the same issue on a different machine as well. I was surprised when I wasn't able to find a discussion of the problem on line.

It seems that every once in a while, I'll be working away in R and suddenly the keyboard language settings will randomly change.

for example, when I type "?", I'll get "e with an accent", or when I type "^", I'll get "?".

Does anyone know how to debug this? Sorry if this has already been addressed...

Answer (score 2):

This does not sound like an R bug, but like a Windows bug. I had the same experience inside some games. The key combination `ALT + SHIFT` is often used in windows to switch keyboard layout. Disabling this keyboard shortcut will fix this problem.

Comment: At least on my Windows machine, it's `ALT + SHIFT` to toggle languages, but that definitely sounds like the issue.

Comment: I would have thought so as well, but when I retype the same keys in an alternative text editor, the error no longer occurs. I'll remember these keystrokes for the next time the error occurs.

Comment: and update this q title to be accurate, it's not a bug but a feature of Windows and R . . .

Comment: @Thomas updated the keycombination to `ALT + SHIFT`.